# How to you solve this code

Tags: arrays, loops, construct

my code is this I have to manipulate stored data in the array to print individual elements of the array .ie the third and fifth team members names

```
     public class project 
      {
 public static void main(String[]args)
     {
   String[]players = TheTeamPlayers();
    printStringArray(players);
       }
    public static String[] TheTeamPlayers()
      {
String[]players={"Mark Thompson","John Carey","Pat Buckley","MichaelO'Connor","Finbarr Noonan","Kevin Drogan","Ray Kelly","Jonathan Shannon","Ronan Linehan"};
return players;
}
public static void printStringArray(String[]strings)
{
for(String s : strings)
{
System.out.println(" The Team Players Names Are: " + s );
}
}
    }
```

Comment: You forgot the part where you ask a question.  In what way does this code not work as expected?  What have you tried and where are you stuck?  Also, formatting the code to be human-readable might help humans read your code.

Comment: the Java code  displays all names with :The Team Players Names Are
like this
The Team Players Names Are:Mark Thompson"
The Team Players Names Are:John Carey
The Team Players Names Are:Pat Buckley
The Team Players Names Are: Michael O'Connor
etc
 but also i need to also print out the line"the third and fifth members names are "Pat Buckley","Finbarr Noonan"
I've spent countless hours trying different ways and mouse pad has worn out but my question is how to solve the code.I'm new to coding but I've no idea how to solve it please help

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate like this:

```
 public static void  printStringArray(String[] players) { 
   for (int i =0; i < players.length;  i++)
    { 
       System.out.println(" The Team Players Names Are: " + players [i]); 
     } 
   }
```

You should name variables self-descriptive also to avoid confusion.